# get the nth-child number of an element

Tags: jquery

If I have a group of elements like this:

```
<div class="slides">
    <div class="frame">1</div>
    <div class="frame active">2</div>
    <div class="frame">3</div>
</div>
```

How do I get the nth-child number within "frame" elements of the element with the "active" class?

The below would return 1 (because there is one element with the class "active"), instead of 2 (because the element with the "active" class is the second element with the "frame" class), which is what I want it to return.

```
$('.active').index();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code is correct:

```
$('.active').index();
```

It returns `1` because the three elements are indexed as `0, 1, 2` (`0` is the first element)

If you moved the `.active` class to the last of the three `.frame` divs, the output of `$('.active').index();` would be `2`

From the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

- Read more: [jQuery .index() Docs](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 0):

from [api.jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

> We get back the zero-based position

So your first element is `0`